# SQL Connection Issues... next steps

Tags: sql, azure

We've released a new game on Facebook that uses SQL Azure and we're getting intermittent connection timeouts.

I dealt with this earlier and implemented a 'retry' solution that seemed to have dealt with the transient connection issues.

However, now that the game is out I'm seeing it happen again. Not often, but it is happening. When it happens, I try logging into the SQL Azure Management web portal and I get a connection timeout there too. Same with trying SSMS.

The query itself is the first one of the game and it's a simple select on a table with 4 records.

After about 4 minutes, the timeouts stop and everything is good for a day or two.

Since these are players around the country, I don't have direct contact with the users.

I'm looking for any advice on how I can figure out what's going on.

Thanks,
Tim

FYI: http://apps.facebook.com/RelicBall/

Comment: It's a connection issue with Azure. You should use their support channels.

Comment: This sounds to me like you're doing "no no" activities in Azure and you're being throttled because of it. This can happen if you have too many open connections, too many long-running transactions, and for some other reasons as well. I'm unsure of what all of these reasons are, so you should go research these sorts of things. Usually, it's because of a bug or bad design decision made in your application or architecture.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how much compute you have in front of your database I would put in a limit on the connection pools that can be created with connection string.

Trying setting if for example you have 2 compute in front of the database.

Max Pool Size=70;

SQL Database can only handle 180 connections this is a hard limit. You can find for example when you are hitting the connection limit a retry framework will make the matter worse as it will try to connecting for a period of time leading to further downtime. This might be the reason you see several minutes as the compute retry frameworks give up.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff394114.aspx

Have a look with the following:

```
-- monitor connections
SELECT
      e.connection_id,
      s.session_id,
      s.login_name,
      s.last_request_end_time,
      s.cpu_time
FROM
      sys.dm_exec_sessions s
      INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections e
      ON s.session_id = e.session_id
GO
```

You should try to add cache to you application design, this can greatly reduce you application over head on the database and is recommend practice with SQL Azure. Especially as you can have connection issues. I have seen this type of issue before and it was connection limits so maybe worth investigating a bit of time in that direction to see if that causes. If not I would open a ticket to MS Support.

hths, Goodluck.

EDIT: Premium Database obviously raise the limits on connections so worth of investigation also as quick fix to this issue and potentially a long run one.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/dataplatforminsider/archive/2013/07/23/premium-preview-for-windows-azure-sql-database-now-live.aspx